# R loop function over time

Tags: r, loops, csv, maps

First off I'd like the apologize for any vague descriptions here. It's my first week on R and I am still getting used to the new lingo.

I am trying to show to movement of bike sharing stations over the course of a day on maps. I am using csv data from a website which refreshes every 60 seconds.

I would therefore like for my code to be running every minute which includes getting the data, making the map, printing and saving it.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi David, this seems like a huge amount of work for someone's first week on R. Maybe you can break down what you think are the steps, and we start with the first one, for example, showing the bikes on a csv file for a start?

Comment: Hi! Oh no I have everything else pretty much figured out. As in I can make a map with the data on it and everything. I just can't seem to figure out the loop part.

Comment: movement can also be created using the `moveVis`-package... http://movevis.org/

Comment: Thank you. That would be very useful if I were to visualize the flow of bikes rather than the stations. Maybe the next project!